# Don't let anyone to ssh on my PC

Tags: 14.04, ssh

When i am in a network, and others know my password, they can easily ssh on my PC.

I want to log them out when ever they try to ssh on my PC. And mail that log ip to root.

So what should i do, which file i have to configure to make this happen ?

Comment: Why would others know your password?

Comment: If someone tries to login or hack through ssh.

Comment: If you need to have ssh, you could always 1) change the port of ssh 2) install knockd 3) change your password and don't give it out.

Answer (score 4):

1) change your password `passwd`
2) you can turn off sshd if you do not need it

Comment: How to turn off sshd

Comment: "sudo apt-get remove sshd" i suspect

Comment: if you change your password, and then install fail2ban, then people who try to guess your password will be blocked.... and you can still ssh to your device